Is there a way to update with a map of FieldPaths
So in Dart I can do this pretty easily:
final map = <Object, dynamic>{};
map[FieldPath('complex.key', 'other')] = 'my value';
docRef.update(map);

This isn't possible in TS/JS though, as you can't have classes as index types:
const map: { [key: FieldPath]: any } = {};
map[new FieldPath(['complex.key', other])] = 123; // Type 'FieldPath' cannot be used as an index type.ts(2538)

Is this possible in the Nodejs API?
